# Authentication failure checking out svn:extrenals with svnX

Tags: macos, svn

I set up a repository with some links to other repos via svn:externals property. Checking out from the command line with svn command works well. However if I try to update my working copy with [svnX](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/features/) GUI it gives the following error:

> svn: warning: Error handling externals definition for
>   '/Users/MyName/MyProject/third_party_library': svn: warning: OPTIONS
>   of 'http://svn.external.com/repositories/third_party_library':
>   authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic
>   challenge (http://svn.external.com)

So it seems svnX fails to select the appropriate authentication method while checking out externals. It is strange because if I try to check out the external repo as a stand-alone working copy it works even with svnX.

Did you have already this issue? Are there any way to tell svnX which auth method to use when checking out externals?